# iPhone - iOS compatibilty in Apple doc

Tags: iphone, ios, backwards-compatibility

Ican read in the apple doc for NSData :

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path options:(NSDataWritingOptions)mask error:(NSError **)errorPtr
Parameters

mask
A mask that specifies options for writing the data. Constant components are described in “NSDataWritingOptions”.

Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
```

and for NSDataWritingOptions :

```
Options for methods used to write NSData objects.

enum {
   NSDataWritingAtomic = 1UL << 0,
   NSDataWritingCoordinated = 1UL << 2,
   NSDataWritingFileProtectionNone     = 0x10000000,
   NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete = 0x20000000,
   NSDataWritingFileProtectionMask     = 0xf0000000,
};
typedef NSUInteger NSDataWritingOptions;

NSDataWritingAtomic
Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

NSDataWritingCoordinated
??????

NSDataWritingFileProtectionNone
Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete
Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

NSDataWritingFileProtectionMask
Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
```

How may I use a 2.0 method that takes 4.0 arguments when compiling for 3.x target ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to call the method in the 2.0 way for 3.x targets. You won't be able to call it with the 4.0 format or values.

Comment: You will get undefined behavior if you use that value.

Comment: Seems that is what I've seen in the header file... How may I use it then ?

Comment: It looks like `NSAtomicWrite` is the old 2.0 and 3.0 version name.